# PHP - Using stored value as array key

Tags: php, arrays

PHP has a handy feature to allow to "pre-create" array keys in a form:

```
<input type="text" name="settings[store][this][here]" />
```

Now, in a database I have stored the "location" of a certain value, using this field value:

```
[store][this][here]
```

I want to recall this value in an array call, like this:

```
echo $result[settings][database-field];
```

which would then become:

```
echo $result[settings][store][this][here];
```

**How can I construct my call to do this?**

*I have tried the following, but to no avail:*

```
echo $result[settings][$row[database-field]];
echo $result[settings][${$row[database-field]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By string concatenating you are creating string braces of `[` and `]` so php not treating it like array. Either you need to parse it like this

```
<?php
    $result = [
        "settings"=>[
          "store"=>[
              "this"=>[
                  "here"=>"Got it!!"
              ]
          ]
        ]
    ];
    $vars = "[store][this][here]";

    function getVal($val,$vars){
        $vars = explode("][",rtrim(ltrim($vars,"["),"]"));
        $new = array();
        foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
            $val = $val[$var];
        }
        return $val;
    }

    $final = getVal($result["settings"],$vars);
    echo $final;
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/880737

Or if there is no user input then you can use one liner code with `eval`

```
eval('$final = $result[settings]'.$vars.';');
echo $final;
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/880753

I you directly use like this `$result[settings][store][this][here];` also would work with some notice. but as you are creating by sting concatenation braces are not treated as array.

Live demo : https://eval.in/880743

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to parse the keys from the location (parsing will dynamically adapt to keys of different depths > 0):

```
$result['settings'] = ['store'=>['this'=>['here'=>'stored value']]];
$location = "[store][this][here]";

preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]/',$location, $matches);
$keys = $matches[1];

$value = $result['settings'][current($keys)];
while(next($keys)) $value = $value[current($keys)];

echo $value; // 'stored value'
```

[**demo**](https://ideone.com/NVliEd)

I would be careful about using `eval()` on user-supplied input.

Comment: I think it would not work for dynamic location like `[store][here]` and `[store][this][here]` for both

Comment: I am also agree with you about using `eval()` on user supplied input.

Comment: Yes you made it dynamic now :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the database and use a `;` to seperate them.

You store it in the database like this `settings;store;this;value`

Then use `explode` to store it in an array `$array = explode(';', $databasestring);`

echo the results like this:

```
echo $result[$array[0]][$array[1]][$array[2]][$array[3]];
```

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. But I would like to call the corresponding (last) array key in one swoop, without resorting to manual traversing. Isn't there a function that can be used to accomplish that? 

Something like echo $result[$array]; ?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this. This seems like a bad design though, so maybe try to think this over!

First, you can get each element by itself to access it as a real key in the array:

```
<?php
$result = [];
$result["store"]["this"]["here"] = "test";
$key = "[store][this][here]";

// some housekeeping
$keyArr = explode("][", $key);
$keyArr[0] = trim($keyArr[0], "[");
$keyArr[count($keyArr) - 1] = trim($keyArr[count($keyArr) - 1], "]");
$res = $result;
foreach ($keyArr as $key) {
    if (isset($res[$key])) { // make sure the key exists
        $res = $res[$key];
    }
}
var_dump($res); // test
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kLHh8)

Another way, but **terribly insecure**, specially because this comes from user input, is to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). It will execute whatever argument you pass in as PHP code (see how dangerous?). I'll put it here for demonstrative purposes but **don't use this!**:

```
<?php
$result = [];
$result["store"]["this"]["here"] = "test";
$key = "['store']['this']['here']";

var_dump(eval("echo \$result".$key.";")); // test
```

You'll need to store the keys between quotes for this to work (or, add the quotes later). But you won't, because you **won't do this!**

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VNSR0)